# How to add data property to tags in a Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny App, I want to add to property `data` to some tags. For example,

```
sliderInput("bins",
            "Number of bins:",
            min = 1,
            max = 50,
            value = 30,
            data-title = "Simple slider",
            data-intro = "This is a slider. Use it!")

 HTML("<h2 data-title = 'Welcome to LAI287 basal insulin study' 
      data-intro = 'This is a quick tour of the functionalities in this dashboard.'>
      LAI287 basal insulin study</h2>")
```

In both cases I received a lot of errors. The result is to add `data-title` and `data-intro` to give to the users a tour of the functionalities in my Shiny App.

Comment: Would you be opposed to just including the title and intro as headers above the sliderInput separately?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

```
addAttributes <- function(slider){
  slider$children[[2]] <- htmltools::tagAppendAttributes(
    slider$children[[2]], 
    `data-title` = "Simple slider",
    `data-intro` = "This is a slider. Use it!"
  )
  slider
}

addAttributes(
  sliderInput("bins",
              "Number of bins:",
              min = 1,
              max = 50,
              value = 30
  )
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I receive this error: Error in sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30, : unused arguments (`data-title` = "Simple slider", `data-intro` = "This is a slider. Use it!")

Comment: @Enrico Ah ok, I thought there were a `...` argument in `sliderInput` but there's not. So you can't do that... except perhaps by modifying the function, I'm going to take a look.

Comment: @Enrico But I don't know whether these attributes are placed where they should be placed. Can't you encapsulate the slider in a `div` and set the attributes to this `div`?